# Compare two Directories in Powershell and work with the incomparisons

Tags: powershell, move, directory, robocopy

I try to compare 2 Folders. **A** and **B**.
**B** is a Backup Folder of **A**. Firstly I want to check if any Files have been deleted in Folder **A**, if so, I want to take that corresponding File from **B** and move it. Then I can go ahead and RoboCopy /mir **A** again which will create the Backup.

My issue is how to compare the two directories (A and B have subfolders etc), and then move the Deleted File. Here is the Code which is supposed to do this task.

```
#region | Global Variables 
$backupFolder = "Sandbox_Backup"
$UsbDisk = "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop"
#endregion 

$date = Get-Date -Format G
# Create Log that Script has been started
MyLog "--- Script has been started at $date ---" 0
$testfolder = Test-Path "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder"  
 # If a Backup folder already exist then Compare files and see if any changes have been made
        if ( $testfolder -eq $true ) { #IF_2  

                    # Copy deleted files to BackUp Folder
                    MyLog "Check for Deleted Files on Data_01:\" 0                  
                    $source = $testfolder + "\Data_01"
                    $sourcelist = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse
                    $destination = "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder\Data_01\_DeletedFiles"
                    $testDestination = Test-Path $destination
                    if ( $testDestination -eq $false ){
                        mkdir $destination
                    }

                    foreach ($file in $sourcelist){
                    $result = test-path -path "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01*" -include $file.Name
                        if ( -not $result ){
                        $CopyFile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.Name
                        Copy-Item $CopyFile -Destination $destination
                        Remove-Item $CopyFile
                        }

                    }

                    # Start Synchronizing Data_01:\
                    MyLog "Start Synchronizing Data_01:\" 0
                    Robocopy "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\HP-Sandbox\Data_01" "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder\Data_01" /mir /r:2 /w:3 /M /XD VM_*

                    MyLog "Data_01:\ is up to Date" 0 
        } #IF_2
```

**UPDATE 1**

I kept working on the Code and figured out that the issue seems to be here:

```
            $result = test-path -path "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01*" -include $file.Name
```

It will always return false, because it is not really doing what I intended it to do I guess. It's supposed to go through every File in the **B** folder and check if that File exists in **A**.

**Answer**

I was able to get the Script done with latkins' answer.
For reference, here is the Full script.

```
#region | Global Variables 
$backupFolder = "Sandbox_Backup"
$UsbDisk = "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop"
#endregion 

$date = Get-Date -Format G
# Create Log that Script has been started
MyLog "--- Script has been started at $date ---" 0

        $testfolder = Test-Path "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder"  

        # If a Backup folder already exist then Compare files and see if any changes have been made
        if ( $testfolder -eq $true ) { #IF_2  

                    # Copy deleted files to BackUp Folder
                    MyLog "Check for Deleted Files on Data_01:\" 0
                    # Set Data_01 as Source
                    $source = "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder\Data_01"
                    # Get all Items
                    $sourcelist = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse
                    # Choose as Destination the DeletedFiles Folder
                    $destination = "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01\_DeletedFiles"
                    mkdir $destination

                    # Check if a File or Folder exists in the BackUp folder but not on the Server
                    foreach ($file in $sourcelist){
                        # First we have to check if the File we have in the Backup still exists on the Server; however, we do not care about the DeletedFiles Folder
                        if ( -not ($file.Name -eq "_DeletedFiles" )){ 
                            $fullPath = "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01" + $file.FullName.Substring($source.Length)
                            $result = test-path $fullPath
                            # If it doesn't exist then we go ahead and Copy the File to the DeletedFiles Folder on the Server, 
                            # which will later be copied to the BackUp and then deleted of the Server
                            if(-not $result ){
                                $CopyFile = $source + $file.FullName.Substring($source.Length)
                                Copy-Item $CopyFile -Destination $destination -force
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    # Start Synchronizing Data_01:\
                    MyLog "Start Synchronizing Data_01:\" 0
                    Robocopy "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01" "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder\Data_01" /mir /r:2 /w:3 /M /XD VM_*

                    #Delete the DeletedFiles Folder from Server and keep it only on the BackUp
                    Remove-Item $destination

                    MyLog "Data_01:\ is up to Date" 0 
        } #IF_2

        else { #Else_2

                    mkdir "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder" 

                    # Start Copying Data 
                    MyLog "Start Backing up Data_01:\" 0
                    Robocopy "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01" "$UsbDisk\$backupFolder\Data_01" /mir /r:2 /w:3 /XD VM_*

        }

# Delete All Files in _DeleteFiles Folder which are Older than 60 Days
```

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, Robocopy does this already.

Comment: The issue is that I would like to save the Files RoboCopy would automatically delete with /mir. That's why I want to see first which Files are Deleted on A, to move them to a "_DeletedFiles" Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct the full path for each potential file, rather than relying on a potentially costly recursive wildcard search.

Each `$file` comes from some subdirectory of `$source`, so the full path (given by `$file.FullName`) can be shortened to the "relative" path by dropping the first `$source.Length` chars from `$file.FullName`.  Take your new root path and add it to this relative path, and you've got the new full path.

```
$fullPath = "C:\Users\pullrich\Desktop\Sandbox\Data_01" + $file.FullName.Substring($source.Length)
$result = Test-Path $fullPath
```